# How to enable Quick Start button in Lenovo S100 ideapad using Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, application-development, lenovo, quickly, ubuntu-netbook

I'm using `lenovo s100 ideapad` with Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit version.

After turnoff the system when I press Quickstart button it not boot and notice:
"quickstart is not install on your computer or not install Quickstart ...to use please  install Lenovo Quick Start Install".

How can I use the QS button?